# opposite of itertools.dropwhile (how to stop generators after N iteration)

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

is there a simple way to stop an iterator after `N` loops? Of course I can write something like:

```
for i, val in enumerate(gen()):
    if i > N: break
```

but I would like to write something like

```
for val in stop_after(gen(), N):
    ...
```

I tried with `itertools.dropwhile` but it seems to do the opposite. Of course I can rewrite `itertools.dropwhile` with the inverse logic, but I am wondering if there is something already implemented.

Comment: So... `takewhile`? Or if you want a certain number, rather than having a conditional, you could use an `islice` or simple `for _ in range(N):`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `islice`:

```
for val in itertools.islice(gen(), N):
    ....
```

Assuming that your example was meant to be:

```
for i, val in enumerate(gen()):
    if i > N: break
```

Comment: @EugeneSoldatov no, `islice` is still an iterator. Or if you mean `enumerate`, that's a list in 2.x but an iterator in 3.x.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Thanks, didn't know about it.

Comment: The result of `enumerate` is an iterator in Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @DanD. ah, [you're right](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) - you get so used to `range`, `zip`, etc. being lists in 2.x!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `itertools.takewhile`:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile

Comment: `takewhile` evaluate a predicate on the output of the generator, it doesn't count